# Angular-Cli force component to reload image cache

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have a project in Angular CLI, it has the lft menu (where I store some navigation and user informations **include user image**. On the right side there is other part of page.

I have a feature that user can change his image. Its working like charm but when I change it, the picture in the left menu is old one (the URL is the same, when I past URL to the browser I can see the new image). I guess its becouse the left panel wont refresh when I upload new image si It has cache of old image.

Is there any way how to solve it? Something like force component to refresh, delete image cache etc?

Comment: You sure it is not the browser's cache? You can check in the network tab if it is "reloaded" from cache, theb you can add timestamp to the file or something similar

Comment: There are some requests in the network tab after submitting the form. I can see the new picture after f5 reload.

Comment: The question is pointless because it's unknown what 'the picture in the left menu' is about. Code-related question should contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you post code showing how you are rendering your html for this so we can provide some assistance in what you can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, the browser doesn't do request to image, because it's cached. It's because image path is the same.

So you can put **timestamp** to image path at the end:

```
 //   <img [src] = '/path/to/image?timeStamp=123123' />


    class SomeComponent{
    imageSrc: string = '/path/to/image';
//    getTimeStamp(): number{
//     return Date.now();
//    }

    // or call this when you need update image

    updateImageSrc(): string{
       this.imageSrc= `/path/to/image?timeStamp=${Date.now()}`

    }

    }
```

Update:

```
 <img [src] = "imageSrc" />
```

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-browser-image-cache). Look at network tab