# Profile Picture not updating across components Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a change profile picture modal that pops up so you upload the image press save and what should happen is that the profile picture is updated across the site but that doesnt happen, only after you refresh the profile picture has updated

my save function on the profile picture change modal

```
save(): void {
    const self = this;
    this.saving = true;
    self._profileService.updateProfilePicture(input)
        .finally(() => { this.saving = false; })
        .subscribe(() => {
            const self = this;
            self._$jcropApi.destroy();
            self._$jcropApi = null;
            abp.event.trigger('profilePictureChanged');
            console.log('changed');
            this._userService.updateProfilePicture();
            self.close();
        });
}
```

so when the user presses save it uploads the image then it calls the updateProfilePicture function on my user service...

my user service is set up like so..

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
 import { Subject } from 'rxjs/subject';


 @Injectable()
 export class UserService {
      private profilePictureSource = new Subject<any>();

      profilePicture = this.profilePictureSource.asObservable();

      updateProfilePicture() {
          this.profilePictureSource.next();
      }
 }
```

then in the component I want the profile picture to change

```
 import { UserService } from '/userService'; 
 import { ProfileService } from '/profileService';

 export class ....

 profilePicture: any;

 constructor(
     private _userService: UserService,
     private _profileService: ProfileService
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    // grab the profile picture on init
    this.userPic();
    // Listen for profile picture change
    this._userService.profilePicture.subscribe(result => { 
      this.userPic(); 
    } 
 }

userPic() {
  this._profileService.getProfilePicture().subscribe(result => {
    if (result && result.profilePicture) {
      this.profilePicture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.profilePicture;
    }
  });
}
```

then in my HTML

```
<img [src]="profilePicture" />
```

I tried to comment out `self.close();` just incase that was causing an issue like it was closing before it got a change to call the service but that didnt change anything

**EDIT**

When I use the chrome debugger Ive put breakpoints on all the functions and the service call.. when I press save the userService function triggers a breakpoint.. but no other functions in the stack are called after that Im not sure why?

**2nd EDIT**
Ive followed Abylay Kurakbayev answer and changed

```
 profilePicture = this.profilePictureSource.asObservable(); //from
 profilePicture = this.profilePictureSource; //to
```

but that didn't fix the issue

**EDIT 3**

here is the getProfilePicture() function

```
getProfilePicture(): Observable<GetProfilePictureOutput> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/Profile/GetProfilePicture";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    let options_ : any = {
        method: "get",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json", 
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };

    return this.http.request(url_, options_).flatMap((response_ : any) => {
        return this.processGetProfilePicture(response_);
    }).catch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof Response) {
            try {
                return this.processGetProfilePicture(response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<GetProfilePictureOutput>><any>Observable.throw(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<GetProfilePictureOutput>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
    });
}
```

**EDIT 4**
This is the processGetProfilePicture() method

```
protected processGetProfilePicture(response: Response): Observable<GetProfilePictureOutput> {
    const status = response.status; 

    let _headers: any = response.headers ? response.headers.toJSON() : {};
    if (status === 200) {
        const _responseText = response.text();
        let result200: any = null;
        let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
        result200 = resultData200 ? GetProfilePictureOutput.fromJS(resultData200) : new GetProfilePictureOutput();
        return Observable.of(result200);
    } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
        const _responseText = response.text();
        return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
    }
    return Observable.of<GetProfilePictureOutput>(<any>null);
}
```

**EDIT 5**

Im wondering if there is a way to force refresh the component that the `userPic()` function is in?? Because the profile picture updates as soon as you refresh the page??

Thanks

Comment: can you console `result.profilePicture;` and see if you are getting the value

Comment: @brk so I get the console.log the first time but when I press save I dont get a console.log at all..

Comment: @brk If I debug, the first time I init the page the breakpoints trigger but when I press save the breakpoints dont trigger again

Comment: my understanding is if on save `userPic` is called it will et the image. So the problem may be that it is saving the pic in db but it is not calling the `userPic` function

Comment: @brk   I put a console.log('changed') right before the `this._userService.updateProfilePicture();` and that runs so Im not sure why it wouldnt call the service

Comment: You need to put it inside `userPic` that will confirm wethe the function is getting called or not

Comment: @brk, yes I understand that. I have a `console.log()` in both functions I get the console.log() from the save function but not from the `userPic()` so obviously the userPic() is not running but I have no idea why

Comment: Can you show us the code of profileService?

Comment: @RavinderPayal check edit*

Comment: The PorfileSevice class is not there in your edit

Comment: What kind of ChangeDetection strategy are you using? I you are using the OnPush strategy you have to notify the components about the change.

Comment: @JulianSim what do you mean? I have a few other services set up the exact same way that are working not sure why this isnt?

Comment: @JuvenileSnow without knowing what happening inside ProfileService class, no one can exactly point out what's problem there.

Comment: @RavinderPayal the ProfileService class is generated with nswag, it has a few methods inside it what exactly would you need to see?

Comment: Maybe problem with image cache? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49339932/5677886

Comment: @Yerkon this could be the problem... I will let you know if this works

Comment: @JuvenileSnow `self._profileService.updateProfilePicture(input)` wjat's happening inside this method and who's listening this event emit: `abp.event.trigger('profilePictureChanged');`  who has subscribed to this empty subject and why a null next ? `this.profilePictureSource.next();`

Comment: @Yerkon, no that didnt seem to fix it..

Comment: Why its  get request type is JSON ??

Comment: @xdeepakv the profilePictureService is generated from a NSWAG I didnt write the code

Comment: If nothing is working out for you, I suggest you toggle the profile image with `ngIf` , so that it will re render. Just make it false for a moment and then make true so it will render with updated `src`.

Comment: @BhushanBabar not sure what you mean sorry

Answer (score 0):

From what I see `UserService` how is declared in the providers ?

> In order to check this

1. `a console.log() in the UserService constructor to see if the constructur is called multiple times`
2. `also check the providers from components you should have only one provider.`

> You must have the same istance in order for this flow to work as you
>   are describing it. If you have one instance across all components can you make a plunker or provide some access to the full implementation of the components.

Comment: Sorry not entirely sure what you mean??

Comment: UserService seems to trigger the update of profile service. when you call the method `updateProfilePicture` what I mean is to check where is declared UserService as a provider.
`@Component({
   providers: [UserService]
})`
Something like this or in the `@NgModule` and also the profileService in order for them to connect correctly you need to have one instance of UserService and one of ProfileService. If they are declared in `@Component` this means that each component will have it's own userService instance which is different from one used in the save function.

Comment: If that's not the case try to make a plunker with the example I will try to help

Comment: Oh okay I understand now, the service is definitely working properly because I have about 10 other calls in there that work perfectly fine, I have another function that updates another part of my app the exact same way in a similar location and that works just for some reason the getProfilePicture doesnt work

Comment: Can you post the implementation fo `getProfilePicture` here you have just the call to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170657/discussion-between-nicu-and-juvenile-snow).

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be caused by Angular digest too, because I ran and checked your code, I'm able to listen to `profilePicture` Observable every time. So below block will execute every time, Which calls `getProfilePicture` always.

```
this._userService.profilePicture.subscribe(result => { 
      this.userPic(); 
}
```

I can see on `ngOnInit()` you are able to fetch profile pic using `userPic()` but not on observable level. So I doubt that you might be doing some Javascript level manipulations on your data, which Angular will not be aware of. I faced this issue multiple times, So I'm not sure if you are doing anything like that in `this.processGetProfilePicture(response_)` method or somewhere else. Please make sure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry Im not quite sure what you mean

Comment: There's a small conflict between Angular and Other javascript libraries including javascript. If you change your data outside angular and assign it Angular model variable, Angular watchers will not listen to them. So your "profilePicture" will not be updated unless you refresh it.

Comment: I'd like to see what you are doing in "processGetProfilePicture" method. Maybe you want to take a look at https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef. It'll help in informing Angular watchers to look for new changes.

Comment: please see my latest edit I have added processGetProfilePicture

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
userPic() {
  this._profileService.getProfilePicture().subscribe(result => {
    if (result && result.profilePicture) {
      this.profilePicture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.profilePicture;
    }
  });
}
```

to

```
userPic() {
  this._profileService.getProfilePicture().subscribe(result => {
    if (result && result.profilePicture) {
      this.profilePicture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.profilePicture;
    }
  }, (err) => console.log(error));
}
```

**Edit**

getProfilePicture(): Observable {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/Profile/GetProfilePicture";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

```
let options_ : any = {
    method: "get",
    headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json", 
        "Accept": "application/json"
    })
};

return this.http.request(url_, options_).flatMap((response_ : any) => {
    console.log(respone); // <-----
    return this.processGetProfilePicture(response_);
}).catch((response_: any) => {
console.log(response); // <-----
    if (response_ instanceof Response) {
        try {
            return this.processGetProfilePicture(response_);
        } catch (e) {
console.log(e);//<--------
            return <Observable<GetProfilePictureOutput>><any>Observable.throw(e);
        }
    } else
        return <Observable<GetProfilePictureOutput>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
});
```

}

And see if there is anything in console regarding this. I have marked my addition into code as `//----`

Comment: No error in the console, The problem Is I dont think the userPic() function is running, but it is being called when you click save

Comment: Check the edit and please co-operate with SO people by providing complete code using https://stackblitz.com or something similar

Comment: I cant make a stackblitz with the same conditions seeing as I cannot connect to my database via stackblitz nor will I have the generated code that is used to, I could easily just create a service that updates a profilePicture but.. it wouldnt replicate my problem

Comment: We just want to see the related code, we need not run it, as many things are still missing-in code provided by you

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but should work. Call the function inside a timeout after you changed the picture. This will trick Angular to reload the view.

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.userPic();
  }, 500);
```