# Angular image not updating

Tags: angular, image, caching

When i update or upload a image. It stores cache on show old image.I want to show updated image when i updated image. I don't want to hard reload browser.I am using Angular

```
<img [src]="src+ time()"/>
```

It didn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular-Cli force component to reload image cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338790/angular-cli-force-component-to-reload-image-cache)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this -

```
<img [src]="src + '?lastmod=newTimeStamp'"/>
```

Here `newTimeStamp` should be replaced with new time stamp.

Or

```
<img [src]="src + '?lastmod=' + Math.random()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.But that doesn't quite well fro me. here is my view code
  <div *ngIf="user.imagePath"><img width="100" style="margin-bottom:10px"  [src]="serverBaseurl + '/uploads/' + user.imagePath +'?'+'lastmod=' +checkDate" /></div>

Comment: Yes, I am.Please give me a better solution.

Comment: Then you should set expiry header for cache control from your server and there only you can forcefully clear cache for every image to load, as on client side this the best recommended way to clear cache of images.

Comment: Can you share code sample. I couldn't understand what you say

Comment: 'Then you should set expiry header for cache control from your server' why i have to do this?

Comment: Is there any way to solve this using only angular (frontend )

Comment: I don't think so, I know only this way which I added as answer.